# Requesting RSS feed works in browser but not using XmlDocument.Load()

Tags: c#, rss, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to programmatically download an RSS feed using a simple C# WebForms application.

The URI for the RSS feed contains an authorisation token which is specific to my login details.

If I request the RSS feed using a WebBrowser control then the feed is wrapped in HTML and is un-parseable.

If I request the RSS feed using

```
var rssXml = new XmlDocument();
rssXml.Load(feedUri);
```

Then it returns a *401 - Unauthorized* response.

However, I can open a browser, clear all cookies for the host site (in fact, a rarely-used browser which I've never used for visiting the host site) and use the same RSS URI and the expected RSS feed *is* received. This suggests that the authorisation token in the URI is accepted.

So how come I can't successfully request the RSS feed by using this code?

```
var rssXml = new XmlDocument();
rssXml.Load(feedUri);
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `WebClient` or `HttpWebrequest` (which support authentications) to download your xml and then load it to XmlDocument.

Comment: When you say "which support authentications" you mean authentication cookies, right? Surely an RSS feed doesn't require cookies? Also, like I said in the OP, I've tried the URI in a browser which had no existing cookies for that domain and the URI worked fine.

Comment: No I meant you can send username & password with those classes. Your browser may have cached them. Trying them would be shorter then your comment.

Comment: I've rewritten the code to use an XmlReader and passed the credentials but receive the same response. If I use Fiddler I can see the 401 response but immediately after it is a 200 (OK) response containing the expected RSS feed. From comparing the browser-invoked request to the request from my application, the only difference I can see is that the browser sets the User-Agent in the request header. Is it possible to set this in an XmlReader or an XmlDocument.Load() call?

Comment: I don't know how it can be done using XmlReader, but it is easy this way `using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(wc.DownloadString(url));
    }`

Comment: Thanks very much L.B. - I should have paid more attention to your first comment. I added credentials to your code and it works perfectly. If only you'd written it as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this question for an answer, please see @L.B.'s comment above.